# What if 2 candidates had the same voting result

Tags: discussion

I am watching Ask Ubuntu moderators election.

I noticed that there are 2 candidates who have the same voting result. For instance [@maythux](https://askubuntu.com/users/150504/maythux) and [@searchfgold6789](https://askubuntu.com/users/38094/searchfgold6789) have right now the same result: (5)

But @maythux has more upvotes than @searchfgold6789

If the election ends right now, who might win among them?

Any official SE rule for this?

Comment: Remember that this is still just the primaries. The actual election runs on a different system. I think I saw somewhere that it's Single Transferable Vote - if it is, then each person gets one vote but chooses an order of preference (so if someone's first choice gets eliminated, the next takes the vote instead and so on). So there's a little less chance of a tie than there is in the primary, where people are able to up (or down)vote as many candidates as they like. But it'd be interesting to hear what happens in the unlikely event.

Comment: [maythux](http://askubuntu.com/election/4?tab=primary#post-419884) now appears to only have two votes... and the actual [election](http://askubuntu.com/election/4?tab=election) bit has started.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We throw each candidate into a tank and fill it up with flags.
First person to moderate their way out (and not drown) wins.

---

In primaries the [first-nominated in a tie goes through](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190014/144180).

In the main election, it's a different system as Jez commented. We use Meek STV which is a very complicated (by very fair) single-vote, multi-preference system. You can look it up if you like... The side effect of this is in an organic situation, you're *extremely* unlikely to end up with exact ties.

That said, if one did happen, [Stack Exchange would just add another seat and we'd have an extra moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222405/144180). This is contrary to the standard OpenSTV behaviour which just picks a random winner (that I was previously suggesting).

I've asked for what would happen if there was a massive tie (too many to add seats) but I think at some point things are either going to get random or violent.

Comment: thanks for the effort

Comment: I've asked for confirmation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222362/how-does-stack-exchange-handle-election-ties

Comment: Interdasting. Hadn't expected it to be on a coin flip - maybe on number of first preferences or a decision from on high or something else like that - but for sure a coin flip is fairer that way than alpha or index sorting. (and of course "first preferences" could still very well lead to a tie again - less likely again, but possible)

Comment: If you look at Meek STV you'll see exactly how difficult it is to *organically* arrive at a dead heat. Votes lose value as they're transferred and that results in fractions of votes flying around the system. But yeah, ultimately if you do draw, I guess there aren't too many options (short of a run-off or the fabled "flag tank") that would fix things fairly.

Comment: @kamil Dramatic reversal!

Comment: @Oli I appreciate your way of research. Thanks again